# Small files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to combine small files on hdfs. This is simply for historical purposes, if needed the large file(s) would be disassembled and ran through the process to create the data for the hadoop table. Is there a way to achieve  this simply? For example, day one receive  100 small files, combine into a file, then day two add/append more files into the previously created file, etc...

Comment: "for the hadoop table"... You mean Hive? HBase? Hadoop does not have a concept of "tables"

Comment: Yes, I mean hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are all the same "schema", let's say, like CSV or JSON. Then, you're welcome to write a very basic Pig / Spark job to read a whole folder of tiny files, then write it back out somewhere else, which will very likely merge all the files into larger sizes based on the HDFS block size.

You've also mentioned Hive, so use an external table for the small files, and use a CTAS query to create a separate table, thereby creating a MapReduce job, much the same as Pig would do.

IMO, if possible, the optimal solution is to setup a system "upstream" of Hadoop, which will batch your smaller files into larger files, and then dump them out to HDFS. Apache NiFi is a useful tool for this purpose.

Comment: I have goggled both pig and spark and the results have been less than enlightening , (for example, I've found articles that state Pig uses Hadoop and right now there is no "recommended" solution for appending files. ). Would you know of a tutorial that will help with this item?

Comment: HDFS doesn't have first-class support for file appending. You read multiple files, then compress / merge them into other files.

Comment: Regarding Pig, `STORE` and `LOAD` commands are all you require. Spark, however is more "programming friendly" if you have a Java/Python background. And as mentioned, Hive will also work if you `CREATE TABLE` from a selection against the other, and you can use a different format like ORC or Parquet